# R: Subset dataframe on a column as.factor() producing empty subset

Tags: r, dataframe, subset, levels

How can I get a simple (non-empty) subset of this dataframe where the column being matched is a factor?

Initial...

```sh
> df$STATE <- as.factor(df$STATE)
```

Head:

```sh
> head(df)

     YEAR    STATE              TYPE.OF.PRODUCER ENERGY.SOURCE        GEN
1191 1990 US-TOTAL Total Electric Power Industry          Coal 1594011479
2662 1991 US-TOTAL Total Electric Power Industry          Coal 1590622748
4153 1992 US-TOTAL Total Electric Power Industry          Coal 1621206039
5673 1993 US-TOTAL Total Electric Power Industry          Coal 1690070232
7210 1994 US-TOTAL Total Electric Power Industry          Coal 1690693864
8771 1995 US-TOTAL Total Electric Power Industry          Coal 1709426468
```

Levels:

```sh
> levels(df$STATE)

 [1] "  "       "AK"       "AL"       "AR"       "AZ"       "CA"      
 [7] "CO"       "CT"       "DC"       "DE"       "FL"       "GA"      
[13] "HI"       "IA"       "ID"       "IL"       "IN"       "KS"      
[19] "KY"       "LA"       "MA"       "MD"       "ME"       "MI"      
[25] "MN"       "MO"       "MS"       "MT"       "NC"       "ND"      
[31] "NE"       "NH"       "NJ"       "NM"       "NV"       "NY"      
[37] "OH"       "OK"       "OR"       "PA"       "RI"       "SC"      
[43] "SD"       "TN"       "TX"       "US-TOTAL" "UT"       "VA"      
[49] "VT"       "WA"       "WI"       "WV"       "WY"
```

str(df)

```sh
> str(df)
 'data.frame':  30 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ YEAR            : int  1990 1991 1992 1993 1994 1995 1996 1997 1998 1999 ...
 $ STATE           : Factor w/ 53 levels "  ","AK","AL",..: 46 46 46 46 46 46 46 46 46 46 ...
 $ TYPE.OF.PRODUCER: Factor w/ 6 levels "Combined Heat and Power, Commercial Power",..: 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 ...
 $ ENERGY.SOURCE   : Factor w/ 10 levels "Coal","Geothermal",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ GEN             : num  1.59e+09 1.59e+09 1.62e+09 1.69e+09 1.69e+09 ...
```

One attempt:

```sh
> df[df$STATE == 'US-TOTAL',]

<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
[1] YEAR             STATE            TYPE.OF.PRODUCER ENERGY.SOURCE   
[5] GEN
```

Another attempt:

```sh
> subset(df, STATE == 'IL')

<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
[1] YEAR             STATE            TYPE.OF.PRODUCER ENERGY.SOURCE   
[5] GEN
```

Comment: Does `df[as.character(df$STATE) == 'US-TOTAL',]` work?

Comment: Having factor column does not change anything (`subset(iris, Species == 'setosa')` works ). Can you provide a reproducible example where we can reproduce the issue you are facing.

Comment: @RonakShah The issue was just a programming error on my part. Subsetting by US-TOTAL was in fact working when I thought it wasn't. IL was not working, but that was actually a programming error. I had previously already subset the data by US-TOTAL, so there were no more "IL" left in the dataset!